# How to play 1st Audio on click, 2nd audio on second click, 3rd audio on third click, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, click, toggle

I would like to perform jquery functions.

Play some specific audio on the first click (e.g. beep sounds http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav) of the user, then play the second sounds (e.g.Cat sounds http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals021.wav) on the second click and third audio on the third click and so on. Here is the code.

```html
<body>
  
  
  <style>#container{
  width:100vw;height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
}</style>
    <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();           }
   </script>

<div id="container" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"> CLICK  
   <!--SOUND-1-->
<audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" >
   <!--SOUND-2-->
<audio id="audio" src="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals021.wav" ></audio>
 <!--SOUND-3-->
<audio id="audio" src=" http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals011.wav" ></audio>
  
  
  
  
  
  
 </body>
```

Is there a way to combine the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will solve your all problem you can add more mp3 as you want and whenever clicking the play button it will stop the existing mp3 and play the new mp3 in a row [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz8ane47/4/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
  
  <style>#container{
  width:100vw;height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
}</style>
  

<div id="container"> 
  <button id="play_sound">Click to play</button>
</div>
<script>
    const sounds = [
      "http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav",
      "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals021.wav",
      "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals011.wav"
    ];
        let soundIndex = 0;
    let audio;
    $("#play_sound").on("click",()=>{
                console.log(sounds[soundIndex]) 
        if(audio){
            audio.pause();
                    audio.currentTime = 0;
        }
            audio = new Audio(sounds[soundIndex++]);
                audio.play();
        soundIndex > 2 && (soundIndex = 0);
    })
  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is something like this :

1. First, put this audio tag in your body code : `<audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" >`
2. Then create the function that counts the clicks on the button and switch-case the src of the audio element :

> ```
> let clickCount = 0;
> function play() {
>   const audio = document.getElementById("audio")
>   switch(clickCount) {
>   case 1:
>     audio.src = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals021.wav"
>     break;
>   case 2:
>     audio.src = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals011.wav"
>     break;
>   default:
>     audio.src = "http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav";
>     click = 0;
>   audio.play();
>   click += 1;
>   break;
> }
> ```

That's what I would do if I was in your case, but there are many ways to do it, be free to use my code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple modified version of your code, it's not perfect but only for you to get the idea

```html
<body>
  
  
  <style>
#container{
  width:100vw;height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
    <script>
    let clicks = 1;
  function play() {
    
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio" + clicks++);
       console.log(audio.id)
       audio.play();
       if (clicks > 3) clicks = 1;
       }
   </script>

<div id="container" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"> CLICK  
   <!--SOUND-1-->
<audio id="audio1" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" >
   <!--SOUND-2-->
<audio id="audio2" src="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals021.wav" ></audio>
 <!--SOUND-3-->
<audio id="audio3" src=" http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals011.wav" ></audio>
  
 </body>
```